# function in views not called while sending POST request to django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am beginner to Django and I am working to store input form data to database with using HTML forms.But whenever the request generated, the register function isn't called.

My login form and registration form are in a single web page.My webpage consists a scroll down animation effect on opening of registration form.

Here is my code :

Login.html (with Javascript(jQuery))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/holder/2.9.7/holder.min.js" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" type="text/css">
    <link type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login | Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#lgcollapse').collapse('show');

        $('#reg-uncollapse').hide();

        $('#register-form-opener').click(function(){
            $('#lgcollapse').slideUp(500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#reg-uncollapse').fadeIn(1000);
                $('#lgcollapse').hide();
            },800);
        });

        $('#login-opener').click(function(){
            $('#lgcollapse').slideDown(500,function(){
                $('#reg-uncollapse').hide();
            });
            /*setTimeout(function(){
                $('#lgcollapse').fadeIn(1000);
            },800);*/
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    .nmp{
        background: #ffffff;
        transition: 1s ease;
        box-shadow:  5px 5px 10px #bfc2c4, -5px -5px 10px #ffffff;
    }
    .nmp:hover{
        box-shadow: none;
    }
</style>
<body style="background-color: #e9ecef!important;">
    <div class = "row my-5" id="lgcollapse"  style="background-color: #ffffff!important;box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 18px -2px #000000;margin-right: 0px!important;">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-12">
                    <div class = "card my-5" style="background-color: #e9ecef!important;">
                        <div class="card-title text-center">
                            <div class = "jumbotron-fluid">
                                <h4 class = "display-4">Login</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "card-body">
                            <div class = "card-title text-center">
                                <i class = "fa fa-user-circle fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <form class = "needs-validation" novalidate method="POST">
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <label><h4 class = "text-primary">Username</h4></label>
                                    <input type="text" class = "form-control nmp" id = "usernm" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                    <label><h4 class = "text-secondary">Password</h4></label>
                                    <input type="password" class = "form-control nmp" id = "lgpasswd" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class = "form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class = "form-check-input ml-auto" id="logged">
                                    <label for = "logged" class="form-check-label ml-auto">Keep Logged in</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class = "form-group text-center">
                                    <button class = "btn btn-success"><i class = "fa fa-sign-in fa-lg"></i> Log In</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class = "form-group text-center">
                                    <label><a href = "#" class = "lead btn-link" id = "register-form-opener">New User ? Register Here...</a></label>
                                </div>

                                <hr class = "clearfix">

                                <div class = "text-center">
                                    <button class = "btn btn-danger" ><i class = "fa fa-google fa-lg"></i> Sign in with <b>Google</b></button>
                                    <button class = "btn btn-primary" ><i class = "fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i> Sign in with <b>Facebook</b></button>
                                </div>

                                <hr class="clearfix">

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row my-3 w-100" id="reg-uncollapse">
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "col-md-12" style="background-color:#e9ecef!important;">
                    <div class = "card my-5" style="background-color:#e9ecef!important;">
                        <div class = "card-title text-center">
                            <div class = "jumbotron-fluid">
                                <h4 class = "display-4">Register</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr class = "clearfix">
                        <div class = "card-body">
                            <form class = "needs-validation" novalidate method="post" action="login">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class = "form-row">
                                    <div class = "col-md-4 my-auto">
                                        <div class = "card-title text-dark text-center">
                                            <h5>Customer Name</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class = "form-control nmp" placeholder="First Name" name = "fname" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class = "form-control nmp" placeholder="Last Name" name = "lname"  required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-row mt-4">
                                    <div class = "col-md-4 my-auto">
                                        <div class = "card-title text-dark text-center ">
                                            <h5>E-mail</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<div class = "col-md-4">
                                        <input type="text" class = "form-control nmp" placeholder="Username" name="username" required>
                                    </div>-->
                                    <div class = "col-md-8">
                                        <div class = "input-group nmp">
                                            <div class = "input-group-prepend">
                                                <div class = "input-group-text">@</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="email" class = "form-control w-100" placeholder="E-Mail Address" name = "email_domain" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-row mt-4">
                                    <div class = "col-md-4 my-auto text-center text-dark">
                                        <h5>Phone</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "col-md-8">
                                        <input type="tel" class = "form-control nmp" name="phone"  required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-row mt-4">
                                    <div class = "col-md-4 text-center text-dark">
                                        <h5>Shipping Address</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <div class="form-row  text-left">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder="House No" name = "hno" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder="Street Name" name = "street" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder="Route" name = "route" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder = "City" name = "city" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder="State" name = "state" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder="ZIP Code" name = "zipc" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <input class="form-control nmp" type="text" placeholder = "Country" name = "country" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-row mt-4">
                                    <div class = "col-md-4 text-center text-dark">
                                        <h5>Password</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class = "col-md-8">
                                        <div class = "form-row">
                                            <div class = "col-md-4">
                                                <input type="password" class = "form-control nmp" placeholder="Password" name = "psswd" value="qwerty" required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class = "col-md-4">
                                                <input type="password" class = "form-control nmp" placeholder="Confirm Password" name = "cpsswd" value="qwerty" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class = "text-danger">Please be stay Alert while creating your password !! You will not be able to reset password if forgotten!!!</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr class = "clearfix">
                                <div class = "form-row mt-4">
                                    <div class = "card-text text-center col-md-12">
                                        <h5 class = "btn-link text-center"><a href = "#" id = "login-opener" class = "text-center">Already Registred ? Go to Login</a></h5>
                                        <button class = "btn btn-success mt-2" type="submit" id="reged" ><i class = "fa fa-user-plus fa-lg">&nbsp;Register</i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
            var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
                form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                }, false);
            });
        }, false);
    })();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = {
    path('register', views.register, name="register")
}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from  django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        phone = request.POST['phone']
        uname = request.POST['username']
        emdmain = request.POST['email_domain']
        hno = request.POST['hno']
        street = request.POST['street']
        route = request.POST['route']
        city = request.POST['city']
        zipc = request.POST['zipc']
        desh = request.POST['country']
        psswd = request.POST['psswd']
        cpsswd = request.POST['cpsswd']

        user = User.objects.create_user(fname = fname,lname = lname,username=uname,email=emdmain,password=psswd)
        user.save()

        print('user created')

    return render(request,"This Function Is Called")
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks !!!!

Comment: which url you use for render `login.html` page

Comment: if you want learn as beginner level then https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/  this side is best docs is pretty good but as beginner this prefered

Comment: I had used ```urlpatterns = [
    path('login',include('user.urls')),
]``` in the main project urls.py file

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Ajax to call the function ?

XXX is the date you want to send and the name

I cant see in Login.html where you call register

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'register',
                data: {
                    'XXX': XXX,             
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
})
```

Comment: I am new to django and I learning to submit form data to db, but recently my html web page consists an animation which contains registration form which visibles with slide up animation, Is there any way to register a user in this method ??

Comment: Ok, you need a way for the client to communicate with the server , Ajax is such a way

Comment: The register and login both are in login.html file.So, I had called login in form action.

Comment: Can you explain me how can I call function using ajax.Any code sample or example ??

Comment: I am still getting confused in ajax, is it possible to implement in python ??

Comment: You need to do it in JavaScript